# Установка Windows и Linux на GPT диск и EFI

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, uefi, gpt

Как установить на один жесткий диск размеченный в GPT Windows и Linux запускающиеся в EFI?

Comment: @LEQADA, а к администрированию?

Comment: Эм.. А в чём собственно проблема?

Comment: Просто хотелось поделиться хинтом.

Comment: @ComBin, в таком случае лучше сразу ставить галку Ответить на собственный вопрос и публиковать одновременно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо за совет, буду пользоваться.

Comment: стоит задача установить Win7 на бук с AstraLinux SSD GPT. если сможете помогите советом
СПАСИБО!

Comment: Советую не использовать устаревшее ПО. ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно рекомендуется ставить сначала Windows затем Linux, собственно при таком раскладе обычно проблем не наблюдается. Если же у вас уже стоит Linux, и нужно установить Windows подойдет сл. хинт.

Во-первых, нужно озаботиться тем что бы для загрузки Linux вы использовали загрузчик совместимый с Windows, в моем случаи это был gummiboot. Далее ставим Windows (в моем случаи это была Windows 10, думаю на до 7ки включительно должно работать) как обычно, основная хитрость в диалоге разбивки диска (надеюсь там осталось немного места для Винды?) создаем под Windows раздел так чтобы на HDD не осталось неразмеченных областей, и говорим инсталлировать в него. На вопрос установщика о том что он хотел бы создать отдельный раздел под загрузчик ответить отрицательно. Кстати загрузчик Linux должен находиться в отдельном разделе.

Собственно в результате Windows благополучно установит свой загрузчик в раздел к загрузчику Linux и вы получите возможность использовать его в своем загрузчике или как было в мое случаи gummiboot его подхватывает автоматически.

Answer (score 0):

**2017 - Anwser**

Я нашел простой способ решить эту проблему, это доступ к платформе BIOS и изменение конфигурации следующим образом:

Если вы пытаетесь установить Windows 8, измените свойства следующим образом:

**OS Type > Windows 8**

[image]

---

И сделать Downgrade для BIOS, чтобы установить его как раздел диска MBR:

**Boot Mode Selection > Legacy Only**

[image]

---

Я думаю, теперь можно будет установить Windows 8 с разделением диска в режиме MBR.

Для меня проблема была решена.

Надеюсь, я помог.